# How to distinct groups of values?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, distinct

I am trying to build a query that select unique groups of values. I know how to group values and select distinct values, but I don't see how to select distinct groups of values regarless of the order of the elements considered. More precisely:

My XML is something like this:

```
<A>
    <B type="1">value1</prop>
    <B type="2">value2</prop>
    <B type="3">value3</prop>
    <B type="4">value4</prop>
<C>
    <D>XXX</D>
</C>
<C>
    <D>YYY</D>
</C>
</A>

<A>
    <B type="3">value3</prop>
    <B type="4">value4</prop>
    <B type="2">value2</prop>
<C>
    <D>XXX</D>
</C>
<C>
    <D>YYY</D>
</C>
</A>
```

Here I would like to make groups of `<B>` values from all `<A>` nodes and select only unique sets of values. For instance, here:

value1+value2+value3+value4

and

value2+value3+value4+value1

These two sets of values should be only unique if some or all of the values are different.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var comparer = new ElementsComparer();

var result = doc.Descendants("B")
                .GroupBy(x => x.Parent)
                .Distinct(comparer);

class ElementsComparer : IEqualityComparer<IGrouping<XElement, XElement>>,
                         IEqualityComparer<XElement>
{
    public bool Equals(XElement lhs, XElement rhs)
    {
        return lhs.Value.Equals(rhs.Value);
    }

    public bool Equals(IGrouping<XElement, XElement> lhs,
                       IGrouping<XElement, XElement> rhs)
    {
        var x = lhs.OrderBy(a => a.Value);
        var y = rhs.OrderBy(a => a.Value);
        return x.SequenceEqual(y, this);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(XElement obj)
    {
        return obj.Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IGrouping<XElement, XElement> obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This returns distinct groups. A group is seen as the same as another group if the elements in the group have the same values as the elements in the other group.
Unfortunatelly, we need a full blown `IEqualityComparer` implementation to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(/*Your XML here*/);
var vals =
    //Find all A-Elements
    xDocument.Root.Elements("A")
        //Select all their B-Elements to one collection
        .SelectMany(a => a.Elements("B"))
        //Group the B-Items by their value
        .GroupBy(element => element.Value)
        //Select the keys of the IGrouping<TValue, XElement>
        .Select(element => element.Key)
        //Distinct them
        .Distinct();
```

Comment: This doesn't return any groups. With his sample XML it returns 4 nodes. Instead of 7 nodes in two groups.

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` now.

Comment: I Think he wishes to have groups of elements not a list of unique eleents

Comment: So you just have to remove  the `.Select(element => element.Key)`

Comment: @JanP.: No. You group by the value of the `B` tags. That's not even remotely what the OP wants.